# Where to find the list of components of an elementary OS release?

Tags: applications, development, elementary-project

Where can I find a list of applications and other components of the operating system? (E.g., is the desktop environment KDE or GNOME? Where are the names of the applications menu, toolbar at the bottom of the screen, etc.?

It would help to have some sort of breakdown of all system components used, so it's easier to know if an app will work, like "made for KDE / Gnome" and what dependencies will be needed, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Dan can answer with 100% perfection to your question. I am quoting from the link:

[Desktop Development](https://elementary.io/get-involved):

> Our desktop environment and all its apps are built using Vala, GTK+, Clutter, Cairo, Granite and a number of other free libraries. All of our code is hosted on Launchpad.net, a free service for open source projects.

[Desktop code](https://code.launchpad.net/~elementary-pantheon)

[Apps code](https://code.launchpad.net/~elementary-apps)

[The basis about elementary](https://elementary.io/docs/learning-the-basics#learning-the-basics)

Quoting from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_OS):

> **Pantheon Greeter**: Session manager based on LightDM
>   **Wingpanel**: Top panel, similar in function to GNOME Shell's top panel
>   **Slingshot**: Application launcher located in WingPanel
>   **Plank**: Dock (upon which Docky is based)
>   **Switchboard**: Settings application (or control panel)
>   **Midori**: Web browser based on WebKitGTK+
>   **Geary**: Email client written in Vala
>   **Maya**: Desktop calendar
>   **Noise**: Audio player
>   **Scratch**: Simple text editor, comparable to gedit or leafpad
>   **Pantheon Terminal**: Terminal emulator
>   **Pantheon Files** (formerly called Marlin): File manager

*Apps that are compatible with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS should work just as well on elementary OS Freya*.

*Recommended reading*:

[Can I install Ubuntu based applications on Elementary?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3150/can-i-install-ubuntu-based-applications-on-elementary)

Answer (score 0):

A better resource for the latest packages is [elementary.io/open-source](http://elementary.io/open-source). It explains each of the components of the OS and how they work together. It also links to the technical repository for any aspect of the OS for your education. Enjoy!

[image: open source]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Open Source page that wolf mentioned, see the [elementary metaproject in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/elementary) for a list of the components built by the elementary OS developers.